# EF Core 5 translate jsonb field null check to false constant

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have type with jsonb field configured with fluent interface.

```cs
class MyType
{
    public MyJsonField JsonField { get; set; }
}

class MyJsonField
{
    public int[]? Array { get; set; }
}
```

I try to check that array empty or contain some value:

```cs
query = query.Where(myTypes => myTypes.JsonField.Array == null || EF.Functions.JsonContains(myTypes.JsonField.Array, "5"));
```

EF translate query to sql without null check

```sql
SELECT ... FROM myTypes AS m WHERE m.JsonField->'Array' @> 5
```

If I try to create query only with null check

```cs
query = query.Where(myTypes => myTypes.JsonField.Array == null)
```

EF translate it to

```sql
SELECT ... FROM myTypes AS m WHERE FALSE
```

Why does it work like that?
Can I check array is null with EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tracked by issue https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1674. It has already been fixed and will be released with version 5.0.7 of the EF Core PostgreSQL provider (which should come out in the next few days).